# Testing a form array with Laravel 5.4 and phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

What is the correct syntax to post 'AccountApiKey[merchant_id]' in the below example for testing insertion in Laravel 5.4.

In production, the code works fine without any issues, in tests I get the error "table not found" where it is not inserting correctly.  I've asked in IRC but it stumped them so I'm hoping the wonderful community of stackoverflow can assist.

Thanks!

View:

```
{{-- Merchant ID form input --}}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('AccountApiKey[merchant_id]', 'Seller ID:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('AccountApiKey[merchant_id]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Test (See below update for complete test):

```
    $accountApiKey = factory(AccountApiKey::class)->make([
        'merchant_id' => 'test'
    ]);

$this->post($this->urlToUse(), [
            'name' => $account->name,
            'AccountApiKey[merchant_id]' => $accountApiKey->merchant_id,
]);



    $this->assertDatabaseHas('account_api_keys', [
        'merchant_id' => $accountApiKey->merchant_id,
]);
```

Controller:

```
   $account->accountApiKey()->save(new AccountApiKey($request->get('AccountApiKey')));
```

Update as per  Sandeesh comment:

Model:

```
class AccountApiKey extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['last_modified_user_id', 'merchant_id'];

    protected $events = ['saving' => SettingsUpdated::class];

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Account\Settings\Accounts');
    }

}
```

Complete Test:

```
 class StoreTest extends TestCase implements TestInterface
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * Tests all forms are inserting correct into database
     */
    public function test_inserting_into_database()
    {
        $user1 = $this->userAndCompany();

        $this->actingAs($user1);

        $account = factory(Account::class)->create([
            'company_id' => $user1->company()->first()->id,
        ]);

        $accountApiKey = factory(Account\AccountApiKey::class)->make([
            'last_modified_user' => $user1->id,
            'account_id' => $account->id,
            'merchant_id' => 'test'
        ]);


        $this->post($this->urlToUse(), [
            'name' => $account->name,
            'AccountApiKey[merchant_id]' => $accountApiKey->merchant_id,
            ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('accounts', [
            'name' => $account->name, //asserts true
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('account_api_keys', [
            'merchant_id' => $accountApiKey->merchant_id, // asserts false
        ]);

    }

        /**
     * The url which is under test
     * @return mixed
     */
    function urlToUse()
    {
        return 'account/settings/account';
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you configured the test database?

Comment: Yes, test database is using :memory: other db tests work fine and the line: 'name' => $account->name (in post) asserts true (so it is inserting)

Comment: can you share your AccountApiKey model and structure along with the complete test.

Comment: @Sandeesh updated

Comment: Are you sure your testing database is up to date? Might be worth running `php artisan migrate --database=testing` to be sure

Comment: It has use DatabaseMigrations; at top of the test so it runs migration when testing (I believe)

Comment: @LeeJ check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here it is, i found the issue and you have to change your post data to this for the test to work.

```
$this->post($this->urlToUse(), [
    'name' => $account->name,
    'AccountApiKey' => [
        'merchant_id' => $accountApiKey->merchant_id,
    ],
]);
```

At the same time, you're unnecessarily making using of an array input which could use a normal input. If you want then i'll give you an advice to cleanup the code a bit.